# Why are my leaves white when I render, but have the right color in Material view?

Tags: rendering, materials, image

I am trying to make leaves fall to the floor.

The leaves are transparent PNGs imported as images as planes, in which I modified the color of the non-transparent pixels (they were grey to begin with and I wanted to add some color) using this node setup:

[image]

The material view seems to interpret what I am trying to do:

[image]

but the render shows white leaves:

[image]

Not sure I understand why that's happening...

[image]

Comment: It's hard to understand what you are trying to do. Don't connect  a shader output to the color input of another shader, use a mix shader node for that

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's because in your node setup, you connected Diffuse shader output with Emission shader color input. This is wrong. You can't connect two shaders like that. If you want to control color value of Emission shader with other node, use RGB node for example.